# HTML5 Canvas Jittery Over Time

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am creating a website that moves an image around the screen.  Over time, though, the image becomes jittery.  I have a loop that renders the canvas 100 times per second.  For example, if the canvas were to start at 60FPS (example), it would slow down to about 20 or 10FPS.  My graphics card is not a problem.  Does anyone know how to maintain good performance with the HTML5 canvas?

```
    <script>

  var posX = 0;
  var posY = 0;
  var velX = 1;
  var velY = 1;

  var canvas;
  var context;

  var img;
  var imgWidth;
  var imgHeight;

  window.onload = function() {

    canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 128, 255, 1.0)";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 500);

    canvas.addEventListener("click", doMouseDown, false);

    img = document.getElementById("hudson");
    imgWidth = img.naturalWidth;
    imgHeight = img.clientHeight;

    startAction(canvas, context, img, imgWidth, imgHeight);

  }



  function startAction(canvas, context, img, imgWidth, imgHeight) {

    context.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 500);

    context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 128, 255, 1.0)";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 500);

    context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)";
    context.font = "20px Courier New";
    context.fillText(("X Position: " + posX), 10, 30);
    context.fillText(("X Velocity: " + velX), 10, 60);
    context.fillText(("Y Position: " + posY), 10, 120)
    context.fillText(("Y Velocity: " + velY), 10, 150);

    context.rect(690, 10, 100, 40);
    context.stroke();
    context.fillText(("velX +1"), 700, 35);

    context.rect(690, 60, 100, 40);
    context.stroke();
    context.fillText(("velX -1"), 700, 85);

    context.rect(690, 110, 100, 40);
    context.stroke();
    context.fillText(("velY +1"), 700, 135);

    context.rect(690, 160, 100, 40);
    context.stroke();
    context.fillText(("velY -1"), 700, 185);

    context.drawImage(img, posX, posY);
    posX += velX;
    posY += velY;

    if (posX >= (800 - img.naturalWidth)) { velX *= -1; }
    if (posX < (0)) { velX *= -1; }
    if (posY >= (500 - img.naturalHeight)) { velY *= -1; }
    if (posY < (0)) { velY *= -1; }

  }

  setInterval(function() {

    startAction(canvas, context, img);

  }, 10);

  function doMouseDown(event) {

    var locX = event.pageX;
    var locY = event.pageY;

    if ((locX >= 690) && (locX <= 790) && (locY >= 10) && (locY <= 50)) {

        velX++;

    }

    if ((locX >= 690) && (locX <= 790) && (locY >= 60) && (locY <= 110)) {

        velX--;

    }

    if ((locX >= 690) && (locX <= 790) && (locY >= 110) && (locY <= 170)) {

        velX--;

    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It sounds like you are not using the canvas context correctly. Can you provide the code used for the rendering loop?

Comment: If you are using setInterval that could be the source of the problem, as your render may be longer than the interval.. I most cases the browser will not show 100fps so it is a wasted effort. Use requestAnimationFrame for animations. It will render the frames at the fastest frame rate the browser can do.  Also are you doing much in the way of creating and destroying arrays. GC could also be causing the jitters.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "a loop that renders the canvas 100 times per second"? A loop cannot introduce the delay required to manage FPS. You would need setTimeout, setInterval, or requestAnimationFrame.

If you are using setTimeout or setInterval, I suggest you change to using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead. It is much more performant. It does not have full browser support but there is a commonly used [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671).

Comment: I am using an interval that executes every 10ms.

Comment: I definitely recommend switching to requestAnimationFrame. 10ms would be 100FPS which isn't realistic to expect. requestAnimationFrame will allow the browser to determine when to render, typically at 60FPS. This may mean you will need to move any updating into a separate loop, independent of the rendering.

Comment: I need to move the image 100 times per second, though.

Comment: Too bad I guess? You'll have to make do with 60FPS. You can always update the position 100 times a second using a separate setInterval but only render at 60 times per second using requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: setInterval is not anywhere near accurate enough to be using for such animation ... requestAnimationFrame comes with a time parameter that can be used for far more accurate animations - you will have to re-think how you animate though, but it's not rocket surgery by any means - [example](http://html5hub.com/request-animation-frame-for-better-performance/)

Comment: Will the requestAnimationFrame still loop through the function?

Comment: You need to do it recursively. `requestAnimationFrame(function render() { /*do render here*/ requestAnimationFrame(render); });`

Comment: I'm also not _rendering_ 100 times per second, I'm _moving_ the image 100 times per second.  I understand that 60FPS is the peak, but am still moving the image 100 times per second, even if some movement doesn't render.

Comment: Your code is rendering 100 times per second, or at least trying to. Though actually, calculating the movement 100 times per second but rendering only 60 times per second would probably result in jittery movement. You will need to calculate at the same rate that you render.